# UITableViewCell, Delete Button Frame?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is there a way to alter the frame of the "swipe" `[DELETE]` button used on `UITableViewCells`? Currently its centred vertically within the cell, but if possible I would like to move it down to the cyan guide show.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are looking for a strongly true way to solve this problem then you should to subclass of `UITableViewCell` and override the all state handling methods for correct drawing your own delete button (do not call super in those methods). But there is another easy way:

```
@implementation CustomCell
- (void)layoutSubviews {
       [super layoutSubviews];
       if (self.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
             if ([self.subviews count] < 4) return;
             UIView *delBtn = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:3];
             delBtn.frame = CGRectOffset(delBtn.frame, 0, 10);
       }
}
@end
```

Comment: `[self.subviews objectAtIndex:3]` is bound to break sooner or later. Overriding state handling and drawing custom delete button is much better idea.

Comment: yep, if we use array we should check its boundary every time before get access to items by index.

Comment: That really solved my problem. But I have a question. When the Delete button appears, it seems to be moving from original position to the new position I just set which looks weird. How can we make the Delete button to appear from same position where we have set the origin for it.

Comment: @Nitish, You need to implement your own Cell class by subclassing UITableViewCell. You can configure it from a xib and manually show or hide your delete button.

Comment: As @FilipRadelic suggestion here is another example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19412487/1721946

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `didTransitionToState:`,

How about using the `-(void)willTransitionToState:` and setting the frame of the `editingAccessoryView`?

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    if (state == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {

        NSInteger num = 10;

        UIView.frame = CGRectMake(UIView.frame.origin.x,UIView.frame.origin.y - num,
        UIView.size.width,UIView.size.height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try changing the frame for Accessory View

Comment: Can you expand on that a little? I was looking to use didTransitionToState: in my UITableViewCell subclass, but I am not having any luck setting the accessoryView frame.