# Can we change the origin for confirmation Delete button in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which is placed on scrollView. Everything is working fine, but when I am editing the table and touching small circular delete button, confirmation **Delete** rectangular button does not appear. The reason for this is very clear. As the table is scrollable horizontally, the confirmation **Delete** button appears at last of cell which I cannot see in start. And when I scroll horizontally, it disappears.
So, is there any way I can set the origin of that **Delete** button, so that it appears in the start?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it but you can try below code in your

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
    }
}
```

write this code

```
 for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {

        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"]) {

            UIView *deleteButtonView = (UIView *)[subview.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
            CGRect f = deleteButtonView.frame;
            f.size.width = xx;
            f.size.height = xx;
            deleteButtonView.frame = f;

       }
```

Comment: refer this post for Custom cell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861431/uitableviewcell-delete-button-frame

Comment: No Maulik. This is working. This method is called when confirmation delete is touched. My problem is, I can't even see the confirmation Delete.